# Android - RelativeLayout with ExpandableListView in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout, expandablelistview

I have problem with ExpandableListView in ScrollView. I have in my app this layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/carType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text=" "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/infoTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/carType"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/tire_replacement"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tirereplacement"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="@string/add_date" />
        </TableRow>

           //...rows...

    </TableLayout>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/infoTable" >
    </ExpandableListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Looks like this:

[image]

But I can´t see whole ExpandableListView. Only one group header row is visible (there shloud be two) and If I expand it, I can´t see the child. If I remove     `android:layout_below="@+id/infoTable`, there is whole ExpandableListView:

[image]

Do you know, where can be problem??

Comment: Do not nest views which scroll along the same axis. Your ScrollView and ExpandableListView both scroll vertically.

Comment: Yes, but do you have tip how can I edit the layout? I need somehow ExpandableListView below the TableLayout...

Comment: No, it really depends on your design. I'm just telling you that having nested scrolling components that scroll along the same axis has inherently bad behavior on Android and advising against it. How you design your layout with this fact in mind is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.70"
        android:fillViewport="true" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/carType"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text=" "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/infoTable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/carType"
                android:stretchColumns="*" >

                <TableRow>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/tire_replacement"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tirereplacement"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:text="@string/add_date" />
                </TableRow>

                //...rows...

            </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.30">
    </ExpandableListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help you. put a ListView in a ScrollView and fix the height of ListView according to it's item
[How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing/3495908#3495908)